# AutoMLStep with validation_data - how to train on all data?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using `AutoMLStep` and specify `validation_data` parameter within `AutoMLConfig`. My understanding is that this data is used only for validation (comparing the individual runs of automl), so this data is not used for training the model. Correct?

If so, how can I say also to train on this data?

Background: dealing with Forecasting problem and would like to not omit last X data points from training.

Answer (score 0):

Training set: A set of examples used for learning.

Validation set: A set of examples used to tune the parameters.

Test set: A set of examples used only to assess the performance.

when we train models using [AutoMLStep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-automl-runtime/azureml.train.automl.runtime.automl_step.automlstep?view=azure-ml-py) as one of the steps in a Azure ML Pipeline. We need to pass a AutoMLConfig object to create AutoMLStep. you can use the input data to the AutoMLStep is the output from the previous step in the pipeline (PipelineData object).

Comment: the question is rather if I am able to use "all" data for final training to have traind model for timeseries forcasting from the very last period of time (not constantly giving away let's say last 10 data points) - can you clarify please?